# Display none only the table that i am clicking , not all tables

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Basically i am doing a **document.querySelectorAll()** which returns an array of div elements . I have a function which has a **handleclick()** function and each time i click in this button i want the hide the table of the button that i am click on not.

This is what i have right now
[image]

This is what happens when i click one of the dropdrown buttons
[image]

**CURRENT BEHAVIOUR: All of the tables hide**

**EXCEPTED BEHAVIOUR: Onlt the table which is related to the button that i am clicking should hide**

Here is the code snippet of the file

```js
const handleTitleClick = (e) => {
    const row = document.querySelectorAll(
      "div[class*='MuiDataGrid-root']"
    ) as NodeList;

    const rowArr = Array.from(row);

    rowArr.map((r, i) => {
      const somerow = r;
      somerow.style.display = 'none';
      return row;
    });

    console.log(e);
    console.log(rowArr);
    console.log(row);
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You do know a class selector exists in css? Use `.MuiDataGrid-root` instead of your `[class]` selector.

Comment: It's not directly related that's why it's just a comment and not an answer. Just wanted to point out stuff you might not know about yet that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add `display: none` for all tables, but only for the tables associated with a particular hide button. You can wrap tables with additional blocks to reach your goal.
For example:

```
return (
<div>
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      const table = document.querySelector("#table-wrapper-1");
      table.style.display = "none";
    }}
  >
    >Hide table1
  </button>
  <div id="table-wrapper-1">
    <MyTable1 />
  </div>
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      const table = document.querySelector("#table-wrapper-2");
      table.style.display = "none";
    }}
  >
    >Hide table2
  </button>
  <div id="table-wrapper-2">
    <MyTable2 />
  </div>
</div>;

)
```

By the way, I recommend that you use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) instead of querySelector.

Comment: As you can see it's dynamical ,your use case scenarior is a different scenario

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1) select all btn element
const allbtn = document.querySelector(".allBtn")

// 2) add each btn click event
allBtn.map((btn, i)=> {
   btn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
     // add btn data-attr in html and add table same id as own ... 
     // ... buttons data-attr
     let currentId = btn.getAttribute('data-attr')
     //thats current btns table
     let currentTable = document.getElementById(`${currentId}`) 
     currentTable.style.display = 'none'
   })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain your code to make it useful for others.

Comment: I don't want to hide the button , i want to hide the table when clicking the button

Comment: yes add each btn data-attr and each btns table add id same as data attr.
after this when click btn you can get data attribute for example table-2 and select element with id document.getElementById('table-2') that will be current clicked buttons  table. i have edited my answer to top